# Error accessing entry when title has special characters

Tags: slug, entry-slug

I came across a weird bug with a title containing a "%" character not converting into a proper slug. So the website editor created the title "Berlenga: a 100% sustainable island" that didn't get turned into a proper slug. It generated the slug exactly as the title. When she went to make changes, Craft threw in a bad request error.

I was able to edit the slug inside the database and she got back access the entry, but I am wondering if there is a way to prevent this from happening again. I'm using the "Slug Equals Title" plugin, which works greatly for localised entries, and I did activate "limitAutoSlugsToAscii". Is there something else I need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used that plugin, but it looks like they do respect Craft's `limitAutoSlugsToAscii` config setting, which should prevent a `%` from getting into the slug.

https://github.com/internetztube/craft-slug-equals-title/blob/master/src/SlugEqualsTitle.php#L45-L47

But that setting only applies to new entries and newly created slugs, and I'm guessing you enabled the Craft `limitAutoSlugsToAscii` config setting after the entry in question was already created.

You should be good going forward, though.

Comment: That might have been the case. Although I did activate the plugin before. Thank you for your input :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant enabled Craft's `limitAutoSlugsToAscii` config setting, not the plugin.